# facing error when installing magento on go daddy

Tags: magento

hosting magento with godaddy getting error
 I have changed my .htacces and php5.ini file ...

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator and inform them of the time the error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
   I will thankful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your server configuration is compatible for Magento installation first:

[Click here for Server Compatibility check](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-know-if-my-server-is-compatible-with-magento)

Also make sure the file permissio are correctly given.

Change the folder permission of below folder to 777

```
app/etc
var
media
```

Change the file permission of below files to  644

```
index.php (main index file in magento root folder)
downloader/index.php ( otherwise if you will try to access System > Magento Connect >Magento Connect Manager (after magento installation) by logging to magento admin,  you will get 500 Internal Server Error.)
```

[Click here to know the file permission settings.](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/magento_installation_guide)

Answer (score 1):

I just finished a magento installation on a godaddy virtualhost and ran up with the same problem.

The fix was to do the following:

1. In godaddy host administration panel adjust the php version to match that of your magento installation(in my case magento 1.9.1.0 CE -community edition), I've changed it to 5.4.
2. Then on your .htaccess file of your magento's base directory change the rewrite base directive to point to the relative path like this:

   RewriteBase /
3. On this same file, add at the end of it the following: 
   RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ [L]
4. Add the following directives to the php5.ini file at the root of your godaddy's virtualhost(if it doesn't exist create one with the same exact name specified):

   [sourcecode language="php"]
   register_globals = on
   allow_url_fopen = on
   cgi.fix_pathinfo =1
   [/sourcecode]
5. And that's it(don't forget to save all file changes and close the files used.

For a full explanation and more detailed steps go to the following article.
[The article](http://linngoneblog.blogspot.mx/2015/04/magento-godaddy-virtualhost.html)